# Static variables in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In Web application, I am using static variable, when more than one user accessing the same page where static variables declare, it could be conflict  variables?, for example i am storing the session value in static variable, if the two employee are accessing the same page at a time it could wrong process na?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static variable in asp.net page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217697/static-variable-in-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there can be conflicts. You can end up with a lot of unexpected behaviors. Avoid them as you may have concurrency issues.

Comment: ok thank you Icarus, if i place private static variable then what hapen

Comment: @Suryasasidhar: Same issue with private. Makes no difference. What's the need for static variables anyway? Can you elaborate a little more what's your intention?

Comment: if i want to maintain a value throught out the page, if page postback occur then also i want to maintain the value, so which is best process.

Comment: what kind of variable? Is it serializable? If so, you can simply put it on ViewState and recover it. But careful, don't put lots of stuff in there, you don't want to ViewState to become over bloated. Another better alternative is simply to put it on Session. It will be maintained not only across postbacks but across the whole duration of the user's session.

Comment: can i go for session to maintain the value

Comment: @Suryasasidhar: Absolutely, you can and it's probably your best alternative.

Comment: ya thank you i go for session, Icarus i have doubt, if sessions are more then also it going to performence problem na?

Comment: Session is just memory that is automatically freed when the session expires or the user logs out (provided you call `Session.Abandon()`). Now, with that said, it doesn't mean that you should put everything on Session; be conservative, if you are storing a simple value, or a couple business objects, I don't see a problem with that. How big are your objects? How many MB of data will you be storing on Session?

Comment: no simple just a value that maximum 20 characters thats all @Icarus

Comment: @Suryasasidhar: That's it? GO FOR IT! haha heck, you can store a thousand of those!

Comment: whether i have to declare session which i am using,  should i declare in global.ascx

Comment: @Suryasasidhar: No need to declare it anywhere. Session is accessible on all the pages. You can simply do `Session["MyValue"]=variableYouWantToStore;`

Answer (score 1):

Yes conflicts will likely occur, the state of the variable is shared across the entire app domain.

Answer (score 0):

*A static variable has only one value for each appDomain*. It means the same will be shared by all the request in the application . This may lead to conflicts . So never user static variable until and unless you are very sure about the behavior , use session instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's why you should be VERY careful when you use static variables in a web app. You will run in concurrency issues as more than one thread servicing a request can modify the value of the variable.Static Variables Scope is Application Level. If you store some thing in it, then its a wrong thing. If one user saves the data, Same time another user accessed the same page then he will also get the same data. So try to store the values in Sessions.

While this works in single-user environment, What happens in a multi-user environment, if there are 2 users simultaneously logged in from two computers, User 1 sets the value as 200, then User 2 sets the value as 400. after that user 1 invokes the Get Value button. What will he see as the value?