# Thread-safe way to keep track of what gridview row is active

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, gridview

I have a page with a gridview containing some stuff loaded from a text file. I have made it possible to edit specific rows in the Gridview. Once a user clicks a button next to the row, a webusercontrol `UC:Edit` becomes visible and the user can edit the row-item.

My problem starts when I wish to save the edit to both the gridview and the txt-file.
I have to keep track of which row was edited (I dont have any unique IDs and ALL columns can be altered).

The code below shows my current sollution (I'm not sure it's good though). As of now, I save the rowIndex once an edit-button is pressed and pass it to my WebUserControl. There it's saved as a private static int (Had to be static, otherwise it was allways default).

The sollution has to be thread-safe. Does anyone have a better sollution than mine? And also, is my sollution thread-safe?

---

(alot of variable names have been changed to make it more readable)

**ASP**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
OnRowCommand="gvList_RowCommand">
<!-- gridviewstuff -->  
</asp:GridView>
<UC:Edit id="ctlEdit" runat="server" OnSave="ctlEdit_Save" Visible="false" />
```

**CodeBehind**

```
protected void gvList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "wEdit")
    {
        int rowIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < gvList.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if(gvList.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text == (string)e.CommandArgument)
            {
                rowIndex = i;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            if(rowIndex != -1)
            {
                ctlEdit.LoadEdit(/*Some info as a string*/, rowIndex);
            }
            else
            //The rest is irrelevant.
        }
    }
}
protected void ctlEdit_Save(object sender, myNamespace.ControlNamespace.WorkEndedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    //Reading a full text file. Each string in 'lines' contains one row.

    if(e.rowIndex != -1)
    {
        lines[e.rowIndex] = e.workItem;
    }
    //Override the text file with the new list.
}
```

**Edit.ascx.cs**

```
namespace myNamespace.ControlNamespace
{
    public class WorkEndedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int rowIndex { get; set; }
        public string workItem { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Edit : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        private static int _rowIndex;
        /*stuff*/
        public void LoadEdit(string someinput, int rowIndex)
        {
            _rowIndex = rowIndex;
            /*stuff*/
        }

        /*stuff*/
        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*stuff*/
            OnSave(new WorkEndedEventArgs() { workItem = someString, rowIndex = _rowIndex });
        }
        //The rest of the save-things are done as usual (delegates and stuff).
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the static variable because it is ''visible'' within whole application and  it can be changed when any other user will enter the same web page (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217697/static-variable-in-asp-net-page) question). What you are looking for is how to persist data between ASP.NET postbacks (you can also google for ASP.NET State Management). There are many ways to do so for example: Session, ViewState etc. They are described in many places so I'll not repeat the description here. For example see this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100).aspx).