# How to handle multiple connection to asp project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I have a ASP project which is been hosted on godaddy . There are multiple user who will be logging in because of it the project behaves awkwardly as in it wont login , updating any records says it already exists but when single user uses it works fine. Also an server error , which I understood by is there were mulitple connection to the SQL database and it was not properly closed.
I have to make it a multiuser .

SO is there any particular code that I need to write

If you need any part of the code will be glad to share, do let me know.

Heres my connection string in web.config file :

```
<connectionStrings>

<add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source=SQLOLEDB;Server=184.168.47.15;Database=ab;UID=abc;PWD=abc" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

 </connectionStrings>
```

Update code:

```
 string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
                conn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                conn.Open();
                if (UserId != txtenrolleecode.Text)
                {
                    string sqlqry = "select * from Newenrollee where enrollecode=@enrollecode ";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlqry, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enrollecode ", txtenrolleecode.Text);
                    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Enrolee Code Already Exist !!');", true);
                        txtenrolleecode.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                string enroleename = (txtfirstname.Text + " " + txtmiddle.Text + " " + txtsurname.Text).ToString();
                string spousename = (lblspouse.Text + " " + lblspousemiddlename.Text).ToString();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Newenrollee set Date=@Date,HMOID= @HMOID,HMOName=@HMOName,Createdate=(CONVERT (datetime, @Createdate,103)),surname= @surname,firstname= @firstname,middlename=@middlename,designation=@designation,occupation=@occupation,martialstatus= @martialstatus,DOB= (CONVERT (datetime, @DOB,103)),age= @age,nationalid= @nationalid,bloodgroup= @bloodgroup,gl=@gl,sex=@sex,address=@address,mob1=@mob1,mob2=@mob2 where enrollecode=@enrollecode", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", System.DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HMOID", txthmocode.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HMOName", ddhmoname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Createdate", dtcreate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enrollecode", txtenrolleecode.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtsurname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtfirstname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", txtmiddle.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", designation.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occupation", occupation.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@martialstatus", cmbmartialstatus.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtage.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationalid", nationalid.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bloodgroup", bloodgroup.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gl", txtgl.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", cmbsex.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mob1", txtmob1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mob2", txtmob2.Text);                

 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Records Updated Successfully')</script>");

                conn.Close();
                clear();
```

the code is pretty long as lot of fields to update made it short if I miss any bracket please pardon

error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Stack Trace :

```
[InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.]
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +5364576
      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
 FAHIS_Data_Entry_Software_in_WEB.Master2.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +375
 System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
 System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
 System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: I would paste some code to demonstrate how your dealing with users and an example of how your updating records etc

Comment: @horHAY I have not made any special consideration regarding user handling. Basically thats my question

Comment: Post the code where the value is inserted/updated in database.

Comment: This is often due to forgetting that `static` members would be shared among sessions

Comment: @AlexK. can you please share a link or explain 'static' members.

Comment: See if this applies to you:  [Static variable in asp.net page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217697/static-variable-in-asp-net-page)

Comment: @Sukanya this not specific for insert/update, its for whole application however will share it to get better perspective

Comment: I agree with @AlexK. It can be a case of `static` variable being shared.

Comment: I am using `public static string userName = ""` and then keep session in same `userName` variable `userName = Convert.ToString(Session["username"]);`

Comment: If username is static then **all** users are effectively using the same variable & last written value; if userB sets the value after userA has set the value, then when  userA reads it later they will see the username of userB. See the post I linked above.

Comment: @AlexK. right understood `static` any suggestion to improve ?

Comment: Always use `Session["username"]` directly

Comment: @AlexK. some places I have directly used 
  `if(session["username"]!="")` and some as mentioned above. Once app is idle it gives error where I have used directy.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i would do is to make sure the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects are properly disposed immediately after use. You may use the `using` statement to take care of this.

This has nothing to do with connection pooling, but it is better to use a simple `SqlDataReader` if you are looking to read forward only data.

Also, open the connection just before you really need it.

```
using(var conn=new SqlConnection(yourConnString))
{
   using(var cmd=new SqlCommand(sqlQry,conn))
   {
      conn.Open();
      using (IDataReader sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        //read from sqlDataReader now
      }

   }   

}
```

With this approach, you do not need to worry about closing the connection explicitly as it will be taken care by the [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

Comment: Where do I open and close connection in your example